# How to output the format into a file in powershell/azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I`m trying to get my VMs from a subscription so I can then create some commands in python to extract different things from the fabric but to do this the easiest way I would need the file to be saved in a CSV format and each time I try to export the content using powershell its not working.

[screenshot of powershell results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo99h.jpg)

Can you please let me know how this command should be written?

```
az vm list --query "[].[resourceGroup,name,storageProfile.osDisk.osType]" -o table | Export-Csv D:\vmlist.csv -Delimiter ";" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: the `Export-Csv` cmdlet requires that you provide it with a collection of objects whose properties will be mapped to the columns of the CSV file. so ... does your code on the _left_ of the `|` produce such a thing?

Comment: it does not, the Azure CLI output its not transformed in a csv format by the powershell

Comment: then you cannot use `Export-Csv`. it REQUIRES a structured object with ONE level of properties. what is the structure of the AZ output? is it just a bunch of lines of text? if so ... you will need to convert that somehow. without some sample data to look at [NOT a picture of it, the actual data] ... there is no reasonable way to discuss the problem.

Comment: Theres nothing I can share more. Its the default command if you go into the powershell and type:
  az vm show --resource-group "resGroup" --name "VMname" --query '[name,resources[0].settings.StorageAccount]' 

the return is 
[
  "VmName",
  null                                <- or the storage account were the logs are routed
]
if you apply --output format  on the above the return is:
Result
--------------
VM Name
storage account name

and if you pipe the above command to export it as CSV it gives you a complete different information (a lot of numbers)

Comment: **_if you refuse to post sanitized sample data to work with, there is no way that anyone can help you unless they have the exact same setup to give them  the exact same output to work with._** [*frown*] you have proven that your 1st stage output is NOT VALID input for your 2nd stage. if you want anyone to work on it, you will need to post the sanitized output of your 1st stage OR hope that someone has the exact same version of your modules and environment so that they can reproduce your 1st stage output. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my research, when we use the command "Export-Csv" to save output as a CSV file, it will treat the output as an object and stores the properties of that object as columns to CSV file. Now the output of the command `az vm list --query "[].[resourceGroup,name,storageProfile.osDisk.osType]" -o table` is `String`. So we cannot create CSV file according to your need.
[image]
[image]

So if you want to create csv file according to your need, please refer to the following script

```
$result = az vm list --query "[].{resource:resourceGroup, name:name}" -o json | ConvertFrom-Json 
$result | export-csv -Path e:\test.csv  -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]